# knit hook for RHtml in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

In RMarkdown files, you can hack the knit process with the hook `knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {  })` inside the yaml heading. Is there anything similar can be achieved in RHtml files?

Also you can hack the "knit HTML" button with `rstudio.markdownToHTML` for RMarkdown files, and what is the equivalence of this to RHtml files?

Where can I find references/documentation on RHtml files?